# Handling TOTP Implementation (PHP or JavaScript)

Tags: php, security, authentication, totp

I have implemented 2FA (TOTP method) in one of my application. Both Secret key generation and TOTP code verification handled at server side (PHP). In some cases, TOTP code generated by TOTP Application (My case Google Authenticator) is not accepted by my application. I know this is because Time Difference. I am expecting a way to support users from different timezone.

Current implementation behaviour:

**Case 1 (Works perfect):**

- Server Default Timezone set to 'Asia/Kolkata'
- User enabling TOTP from India
- User always logging in from India

**Case 2 (Login Failed):**

- Server Default Timezone set to 'Asia/Kolkata'
- User enabling the TOTP from India
- Logging in from different Timezone

**Case 3 (Login Failed):**

- Server Default Timezone set to 'Asia/Kolkata'
- User enabling the TOTP from different Timezone
- User Logging in from different Timezone

How normally TOTP will be integrated in a application to support users from different timezone?

Generating Secret and Verifying from client side (JS) is best practices?

Answer (score 3):

You should always use UTC as the Timezone . That is the easiest approach.

Comment: Yep. Set server/database to UTC. Let users pick a timezone and change the dates you display into their chosen timezone for display using http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php.